# Vaadin wysiwyg eclipce plugin source

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, vaadin, wysiwyg

I use old vaadin WYSIWYG plugin for eclipse and want to make a fork, because it is no longer supported. I see that source in SVN was deleted (it was at
`dev.vaadin.com/svn/wysiwyg/eclipse-feature`).

How can i get source?

Maybe, someone has it

Answer (score 0):

Check eclipse github plugin - https://github.com/vaadin/eclipse-plugin

Comment: No. Github eclipse plugin does not include wysiwyg editor. It was separately in vaadin SVN store as dependency